# Query works via linked server in SSMS Query window ,but fails through SQL server agent job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

We have 2 SQL Servers in each of our environments.  Server A is our Data Warehouse SQL Server and Server B is our OLTP server.  We have the following environments PROD, STAGE, SIT, DEV.  We have configured a linked sever on Server A in each environment to read, write and Exec a stored procedure on Server B.  A SQL job was created on Server A to do a simple select statement from Server B to test the connection.  The service account that will be running all of the jobs was configured as the job owner and "Run as User".  In Prod, STAGE and SIT the test job is working.  In DEV the test job is failing with the message "Access to the Remote Server is Denied because the current security context is not trusted"

I have logged in to server A as the service account and run the exact select command to server B in a query window and the command successfully returns results.

I tried a SQL job on Server A in DEV that calls an SSIS package.  It uses the same service account as the test job via a proxy & credential.  The SSIS package is calling a stored procedure on Server B.  When I run this job it succeeds and executes a stored procedure on Server B that writes data to server B.

I validated that the Service account has administrator privileges set the same across all environments.

I validated that the Linked server has the same configuration across all environments.

I have tried to set up the Linked Server to link the service account on Server A to a SQL account on Server B

I have tried to set up the Linked Server to "Be made using the login's current security context" on Server B

I have tried changing the SQL job to run as an operating system CmdExec.  SQLCMD -E -Q "select * from [Server].[Database].[Schema].table" using the same proxy and credential as the job that is working.  This resulted in the following error 
"A network-related or instance-specific effor has occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server.  Server is not found or not accessible.  Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."

I validated that the servers can ping each other.

I ran SQLCMD -L via the command line to validate that the servers are both present.

I enabled the Named Pipes protocol  on both servers A and B in the configuration manager.

I tried running the test job under my credentials as an SA and got the same

> "Access to the Remote Server is Denied because the current security context is not trusted" message.

I tried copying and pasting the SQL from the test job into a query window on Server A using my credentials and was able to run the query successfully.

I tried recreating the SQL job.

I tried restarting the SQL Services.

The only appreciable difference I can think of between this environment and the others is that Server A is a named instance and Server B is a default instance.

Also of note, the SQL Browser service on Server B is being run by a local account instead of a service account.  SQL Browser on Server A is being run by a service account.

Comment: this seems to be similar:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deepakbi/2010/03/02/job-fails-on-linked-server-access-to-the-remote-server-is-denied-because-the-current-security-context-is-not-trusted-sqlstate-42000-error-15274/

Comment: @TheGameiswar I did see this article the issue is step b asks to remove the service account from "Run as login".  If I do this the job will run as the default SQL Agent account instead of the correct service account